# Applying validation on email format in kendo UI grid in edit mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a `kendo UI` grid. Using it to edit inline to add a new record.
I have three fields FirstName, LastName and Email.
Till now everything was working fine regarding `validations`. I need to apply `validation` on email to check its format.

Validation for email has been applied correctly and its working fine. But I'm facing an issue with the FirstName and LastName fields. These fields still giving the required message while it has values.

Below is the whole code which I'm using:

```
schema: {
                data: 'Items',
                total: 'TotalRows',
                model: {
                    id: 'ID',
                    fields: {
                        ID: { type: 'integer' },
                        FName: { type: 'string', validation: { required: true, validationMessage: 'First name is required.' } },
                        LName: { type: 'integer', validation: { required: true, validationMessage: 'Last name is required.' } },
                        Email: { 
                            type: 'string', 
                            validation: { 

                                    required: { message: "EMail ID Required." },
                                    validateEmailFormat: function (input) {
                                        if (input.attr("data-bind") == "value:Email") {
                                            input.attr("data-validateEmailFormat-msg", "Email format invalid.");
                                            return checkEmail(input.val());
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        },

                        UserLevelsID: { type: 'integer', defaultValue: userLevelID },
                        RoleName: { type: 'string' }
                    }
                }
            }


 function checkEmail(val) {

        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if (val == "") {
            return false;
        } else if (val.search(re) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Let me know where I'm wrong.

Comment: LName: { type: 'integer', validation: { required: true, validationMessage: 'Last name is required.' } }, is a type of integer....you are expecting integer value in Lname

Comment: @Shaz its not resolving the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I think you should return true if the email is valid in validation (not on checkEmail function), otherwise it will keep checking your email. Therefore, after the email address is valid, it will check your firstname and lastname.

Here is example:

```
Email: { 
                        type: 'string', 
                        validation: { 

                                required: { message: "EMail ID Required." },
                                validateEmailFormat: function (input) {
                                    if (input.attr("data-bind") == "value:Email") {
                                        input.attr("data-validateEmailFormat-msg", "Email format invalid.");
                                        return checkEmail(input.val());
                                    }
                                    return true;
                            }
                        }
                    },`
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the the validation from the script and add validation on model level recommended by Kendo

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;

public class RegisterModel
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You forgot to enter a username.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long and 50 characters short", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z\d]+[\w\d]*|)[a-zA-Z]+[\w\d.]*", ErrorMessage = "Invalid User name. No space allowed between charachters.")]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[._A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[._A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
   + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }



    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required. minimum of 6 characters must include letters, numbers, lower case and a upper case.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [MembershipPassword()]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Required]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Min(1, ErrorMessage = "Site is Required.")]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }   


    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex for your checkEmail function.

```
function validateEmail(email) {
var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}
        (?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

return re.test(email);
```